# jQuery form submit event

Tags: jquery

I have a photo upload form that I'm working on that works like this:

1. You click an "Upload Photo" button.  jQuery detects the click and triggers a click event to a hidden "file" field within the form, which brings up a dialog to search through your files.
2. When the user selects a file, the change event is detected on the hidden file field and triggers a form submission. Here is the code:

   ```
   // on photo upload button click:
   $("input[name=PhotoUpload]").click(function() {
       $("input[name=Photo]").click();
   });

   // on photo upload:
   $("input[name=Photo]").change(function() {
       $("form[name=MediaUpload]").submit();
   });
   ```

   and the form:

   ```
   <form name="MediaUpload" method="post" action="/postad/media.cfm" target="Media" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="button" name="PhotoUpload" value="Upload Photo">
       <input type="file" name="Photo" size="30" style="visibility:hidden;">
   </form>
   ```

This works great in Chrome and FireFox, but am having no luck in any version of IE.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I seem to recall that IE won't allow for `focus()` to be assigned to a hidden element, which would probably preclude the `click()` event too.

Comment: What's happening in IE? Any errors? Have you looked in the console?

Comment: Do you see the file dialog in IE?

Comment: Yeah, forgot to mention.  I tried displaying the hidden form elements also.  And, no, there are no errors in the console.

Comment: The file dialog comes up just fine.  It just doesn't submit when I select the file.  I tried adding a submit event also that displays an alert box when the file is chosen.  The alert box displays, but the form never submits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest trying this a little differently:

```
// on photo upload button click:
$("input[name=PhotoUpload]").click(function() {
    $("#your_dialog").dialog("open");
});

//Remove the `.change` function.
// add the form submit line below after the dialog code changes the `Photo` field
$("form[name=MediaUpload]").submit();
```

It's easy to confuse IE with javascript. If it hits something that gives it indigestion, it stops processing the js.